# Can I verify if given address is a correct ETH address using web3j/Java?

Tags: web3js, addresses, web3j

Is there a possibility to verify if given `String` is a correct Ethereum address?

I have found out that there is a possibility to do that using `web3js` I can do either:

```
web3.utils.isAddress('0xc1912fee45d61c87cc5ea59dae31190fffff232d');
> true
```

or:

```
from ethereum.utils import check_checksum
check_checksum('0xc1912fee45d61c87cc5ea59dae31190fffff232d')
> True
```

but I don't seem to be able to find equivalent utilities in `web3j`.

Is there a possibility to verify an address using web3j/Java?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

> WalletUtils.isValidAddress(ethereumAddressHere) // true or false